# DIfference between local , remote and remote tracking branch in GIT

Tags: git

I need to know the difference between types of branches in git - local, remote, remote tracking branch.Below are the commands that i use and give the following output against two branches- dev and main.

**git branch**

```
dev
main
```

**git branch -a**

```
dev
main
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main
remotes/origin/dev
remotes/origin/main
```

**git branch -r**

```
origin/HEAD -> origin/main
origin/dev
origin/main
```

Comment: "I need to know the difference between types of branches in git - local, remote, remote tracking branch" That is absolutely true. You do need to know that. And you've shown pretty well with your code that you do actually know the difference. Note, though, that `remotes/origin/dev` is the same as `origin/dev` (I know, it's a little misleading). You only have access to local branches and remote-tracking branches; you have no direct access to a branch in some other Git (i.e. a remote Git).

Answer (score 1):

For a long answer the git docs will also talk about [remote branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches).

But as a short summary. A branch in git is just a readable name for a commit an will most of the time point to new commits when you do stuff in git.

A local branch is in your local repository and will usually not be seen by anyone else.

A remote branch is on the remote repository and can be used by different people.

A remote tracking branch is in your local repository and shows you where the branch on the remote is. You will update this when you fetch from the remote.